# Мобильный клиент интернет магазина для Android API

Tags: android, api, http, oauth, rest

Здравствуйте,

Сразу скажу что ранее подобных API не создавал, поэтому не очень ориентируюсь в текущих best practice.
Собственно нужно разработать standalone клиент интернет магазина для мобильного устройства.

Требуется естественно свзязать его с сайтом. Для реализации этой задачи было выбрано реализовать REST API.
Как реализовать все запросы которые не требует авторизации, это понятно.

А вот дойдя до осуществления возникли проблемы в дальнейшей разработке, точнее не разработке, а выборе последующего направления.

Задача естественно провести защищенную авторизацию пользователя на сервере и хранить эту информацию на время работы пользователя. Собсвтенно с вебом это понятно как сделать, а по средством API возникли проблемы, точнее даже сомнения.

Существует множество standalone (не webview и мобильная версия) мобильных клиентов, для крупных и не очень интернет магазинов. Соотвественно есть какие-то общее принципы построения защинного доступа с мобильных устройств.

Естественно, смотрел различные варианты защищенных соеденений АПИ, такие как oauth,paypal api ......

Но как-то не нашел одного наиболее принятого способа авторизации. Обычно такой информации много в просторах интернета, а в данном случае очень мало информации о архитектуре построения подобных приложений и API, такое чуство что есть какой-то другой общепринятый, надежный способ это реализовать, задача ведь очень популярная.

Обычно все примеры которые я встречал сводятся к получению данных с помощью `GET` запросов и отправке данных с помощью `POST` запросов без авторизации.

Извините за много писанины.

Вопрос мой заключается в том что, хотелось бы услышать от людей имевших с этим дело, информацию о том как это принято, правильно и надежно сейчас реализуют многие магазины. ТО есть как построить взаимодействие сo standalone клиентом и сервером.

Я не прошу дать мне готовый пример, чтобы поставить свои значения и тупо использовать, хотелось бы наоборот услышать как это правильно реализовать, какие вообще общепринятые варианты решение этой задачи существуют и подобное. Может есть какая-то литература или хорошие публикации на эту тему.
Буду очень благодарен всем кто прочитает, а темболее ответит.
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

самое главное, это какой тип авторизации будет реализован на сервере.
вот от этого и нужно отталкиваться.
по этому однозначного ответа не будет.

в моей практике было и просто логин пароль +сессии в куке.
было и Aopen. была и авторизация через wesocket ...

с другой стороны можешь посмотреть как это сделано в parse.com quickblox.com 
есть app id, secret key , и логин с паролем

> Обычно все примеры которые я встречал сводятся к получению данных с
>   помощью GET запросов и отправке данных с помощью POST запросов без
>   авторизации.

Даже с авторизацей запросы будут сводиться к простому get/post итд.

Comment: Авторизация на сервера обычная Login + Password + Session ID. Я просто не знаю как это реализовать красивее на стороне клиента и чтобы учесть все возможные варианты уязвимостей. И как это правильно связать с REST API или следует уже использовать другое какое-то API для взаимодействия.

Comment: ну 100% невозможно от всего защитится, я пока не сильно парился, все по типу веб браузера, те же пост/гет запросы, а там это и так все открыто, тут же сам сервер берет смотреть, авторизован ли я или нет.

Answer (score 1):

По идее у вас общее апи для web и mobile. Есть сервер который реализует набор веб-сервисов и вы только фронтенд к нему меняете. В случае интернет магазина напрашивается phonegap, в простейшем случае вы им просто обернете существующий сайт (возможно есть какие-то трудности, не могу сказать, на практике не использовал).